# Why I get a backslash in python string

Tags: python, sql-injection

I am learning about blind sql injection. This is a part of my script:

```
...
datas = {"username":"admin","password":"\'or pass like \"x%\" --"}
res = requests.post(url,data=datas).content
...
```

The string after `"password":` should begin with a single quote, so when printing I expect something like `''or pass like "x%" --'` (actually I am not sure whether seeing this will be OK, python apparently changes double quotes to single ones). But I get `'\'or pass like "x%" --'`.

Comment: The string does not contain a backslash. The string's *`repr` representation* contains a backslash, for much the same reasons that you needed to put a backslash in the original string literal that produced the string; a string's `repr` representation is supposed to be a string literal that reproduces the string.

Comment: It is likely a `str` vs `repr` matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're writing strings in python, you can choose to either `"write them with double quotes"` or `'write them with single quotes'`. You only need to escape quotes that match the quotes you used for the string. So, `'This "is" a valid string'`, but to change those double quotes to single quotes, `'You \'need\' to do this'`. So, in your string, you're correctly escaping the double quotes, because you have a double quoted string, but you don't need to escape the single quote.

However, it doesn't matter, because `\'` is still being interpreted correctly by python; it's just printing it as an escaped character so you know it's the character `'` and not the end of the string.

```
>>> "\'\""
'\'"'
>>> print("\'\"")
'"
```